# Pass Powershell parameter into batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to pass an environmental parameter from PowerShell into a batch file, so it calls the correct XML to use for deployment.

PowerShell Script:

```
$SelectedXMLServer = "$x.xml"
Start-Process "C:\DeployTools\Latest_Deployment.bat" $SelectedXMLServer
```

It still calls the batch file but doesn't pass the parameter in.

Batch File:

```
@echo off
CD /D "C:\Deployment\Install\DeployScripts"
echo Deployment will now start
cscript deploy.vbs ..\DeploymentXml\%Deploymentxml%.xml
```

Comment: Try `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\DeployTools\Latest_Deployment.bat" -ArgumentList "$SelectedXMLServer"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I simply change the batch file to 1 it worked

```
@echo off
CD /D "C:\Deployment\Install\DeployScripts"
echo Deployment will now start
cscript deploy.vbs ..\DeploymentXml\%l%.xml
```